# how can I removed some item from #printable section.?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, pdfmake

I'm using pdfmake libraries for making pdf of my page. It works perfectly. But now I want to remove some of the HTML elements when the pdfmake prints the page. Is there any way to do that?

```js
$('#print').click(function(){
        start_load()
        var _h = $('head').clone()
        var _p = $('#printable').clone()
        var _r = $('#not-printable').clone()
        var _d = "<p class='text-center'><b>Invoice as of (<?php echo date("F d, Y") ?>)</b></p>"
        _p.prepend(_d)
        _p.prepend(_h)
        _p.remove(_r)
        var nw = window.open("","","width=900,height=600")
        nw.document.write(_p.html())
        nw.document.close()
        nw.print()
        setTimeout(function(){
            nw.close()
            end_load()
        },750)
    });
```

Comment: Have you looked at `@media print`? [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

Comment: No, I don't look at @media print . Is this really worked? Let me check

Comment: @RobMoll It's didn't worked.!!! another way???

Comment: Have you tried: `$('SELECTOR').remove()` ?

Comment: @RobMoll once I did.!

Answer (score 1):

Try this it's must be worked.! It will remove the elements before the new tab starts to load. Thanks.!!

```js
$('#print').click(function(){
//removed the elements from printable page
      var _r = $('.not-printable').remove();
//start loading the new tab for print the page
        start_load()
// clone the printable section
        var _h = $('head').clone()
        var _p = $('#printable').clone()
        var _d = "<p class='text-center'><b>Project Progress Report as of (<?php echo date("F d, Y") ?>)</b></p>"
        _p.prepend(_d)
        _p.prepend(_h)
        var nw = window.open("","","width=900,height=600")
        nw.document.write(_p.html())
        nw.document.close()
        nw.print()
        setTimeout(function(){
            nw.close()
            end_load()
        },750)
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```